Controlling button press on key fob using microcontroller
I have a battery-powered fob remote, and I want to convert it from being operated via a manual button press to being controlled by a microcontroller.
The fob looks like this:

After making some measurements of resistances between connections when the button is / isn't pressed (always with the 12V battery removed), the circuit appears to be constructed in this way:

The button has 12V across it when not pressed. When the button is pressed, the low side drops to 3.8V (with respect to the fob battery ground). I record 1.25 mA current (using a 6 1/2 digit precision multimeter) through the button's connection when pressed. Strangely, if I feed 3.8V directly into the low side of the button using a bench supply (instead of manually pressing it), then the current drawn by the supply is 3.1 mA (instead of the 1.25 mA when the button is pressed manually).
The microcontroller (Wemos D1 Mini) has 3.3V level GPIO pins, and can supply 12 mA per GPIO pin.
I have a couple of ICs which I am wondering if they will do the job to interface between the microcontroller and the button. They are the Vishay 6N317 optocoupler and the DG417 analog switch, but after reading comments I think they might be unsuitable.

Do you have any transistors?

Something.  With the battery removed, please measure the resistance from the battery negative terminal connector to either side of the switch, open and closed.  This should confirm that the switch is pulling a signal line to GND, not controlling power to a portion of the circuit.

Can anyone explain why this optocoupler isn't suitable? Is it because the datasheet specifies 7V VCC max, whereas I would need the supply to be 12V? I would like to learn.

This coupler 6N317 needs a supply at the output side, that makes things more complex than needed. A simple CNY17-4 or alike with bare NPN output is a better choice here.

Are you sure that 3k resistor isn't 4.7k?

@SimonFitch Yes

@SimonFitch At least, I'm sure that the resistance from the low side of the switch to ground is for sure 3k. However, I'm not sure if this is a single 3k resistor, or else some combined resistance from multiple components or input impedances of the IC pins.

Can it be that the button press is activating the whole 12 V circuit?

Both of your suggested ICs can work, but are not ideal, and would probably require significant supporting circuitry. However, the opto-coupler solution has merit, if you choose the right model.
You can use an opto-coupler, but it will need to be of a type that can emulate a changing resistance (a switch). Almost every opto-coupler out there does that, but the one you suggested (6N137) does not.
This circuit, using the popular 4N25 (also available from Vishay) should do the trick:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Thanks Simon. The 4N25 datasheet shows the base of the output side transistor connected to pin 6 of the IC. However, your schematic shows it not used. Is this base pin not needed for this application?

@teeeeee Yes, the base pin is deliberately unused here

A relay parallel to the button would be a simple option:
SW1 is the original button in the key fob.

The button might also enable the 12 V, might even just in series with the supply voltage of the step up converter. Otherwise the step up converter from battery voltage to 12 V would be draining the battery. The relay option would work, no matter what the key fob circuit is, because the relay does exactly the same as the button.
In this circuit the relay is on the MCU side, so if the button really is in series for all of the power consumed by the fob, the current will be looped through the jump wires. Likely not a problem, unless you plan to run tens of meters of wire.

What about the high current through the relay draining the fob battery though when activated?

Can you suggest some readily available relay part numbers, as examples so I can see the sort of thing you mean.

Kemet EC2-12SNU would work, it takes some space. And if the button is held down for minutes/hours it will drain the battery. If it's just a 100 ms press a few times a day, it won't draw much.

I think the button might also be enabling the 12 V PSU though, so you might want to power the relay from the MCU side and only bring the relay contacts to the key fob.

Okay, yes it could be possible that the button might power the circuit, so safer to only bring relay contacts to key fob as you say. In that case, should the part number be EC2-5NU? Differences: 1) it can be powered by 5V (which the Wemos D1 MCU provides), rather than 12V.... and 2) it should be the non-latching type, as specified in the datasheet, or should it be the single latch type as you suggested?

Yeah, I think the 12 V is only enabled on keypress to save battery. The latching type will only consume energy when it switches state. If you only press for a short time every now and then, maybe the non-latching is better as it won't be left in the wrong state when battery wears out.

So yes, the EC2-5NU would be good.

Changed the circuit in the answer to reflect this. Also added a fly back diode to prevent voltage peaks from relay coil.

While an opto-isolater often is needed to prevent power interaction problems or ground loops, it is not always needed everywhere.  If the FOB is powered only by the battery, its ground is floating with respect to everything.
With a 3.3 V signal, any small signal NPN transistor (2N4401, 2N3904, 2N2222, etc.) will pull the switch circuit down to within 0.1 V of GND with less than 1/4 mA (200 uA -ish) of base current.  That is, with a base resistor of anything from 10 K to 27 K.
UPDATE:
Based on new information added to the OP post, it will take two small-signal transistors (and two resistors) to do what you want.  One NPN to convert your 3.3 V signal to a 12 V signal, and one PNP to do the 12 V switching.  Not at all difficult or complex, just more parts.
OR -
If your 3.3 V signal can source a few mA without sagging more than 0.5 V, it can drive the bottom end of the switch directly through a Shottkey diode.  No transistors, no current-limiting resistors - nuttin.
Schematic later.

Thanks. Just so I understand: you are suggesting 1) GPIO pin connected through 10k ish base resistor to base of NPN transistor? 2) Then, collector tied to one side of the button (which one?), while emitter tied to other side of the button? Any other current limiting resistor on the collector? Do I need to worry about collector/emitted leakage current draining the battery when the fob is idle?

I have edited the OP. Neither side of the switch is connected directly to ground, there are pullup/pulldown resistors. How can I use the transistor in this case? I assume I cannot drive the fob IC directly with the microcontroller pin...

Thanks. You say "convert your 3.3V signal to 12V". However, it seems to me that when the button is pressed then the low side of the button goes to 3.8V. This is due to the voltage divider formed by the 10k and 3k resistors, which drops down the 12V. So, do we even need the 12V anymore, since it is dropped down anyway to 3.8V?

With a PNP transistor across the switch contacts, when the switch is open the emitter will be at 12 V and the base will be at 11.4 V; with no current through the 10K resistor, there is no voltage drop.  When either the switch is closed of the transistor base is pulled to GND, the transistor saturates and the emitter is near 3.3 V.

I have some ZVP4424G Pchannel mosfets, BSS138LT1G Nchannel mosfets, and BC850CLT1G NPN BJTs - are these appropriate to use?

Can you provide schematic for both your options, so I can see how to connect transistors/mosfets? Also, the chip is ESP8266 so can source 12mA max per digital IO pin (for your option 2).
